# Why I don't have DJIMissionManagerDelegate?

Tags: xcode, object, delegates, dji-sdk

I would like to implement DJIMissionManager, but I don't find DJIMissionManagerDelegate.
I have an error who says : "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'DJIMissionManagerDelegate'; did you mean 'DJIMediaManagerDelegate'?"
Somebody have any idea to help me ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

DJIMissionManager has been removed from the SDK and replaced by [DJIMissionControl](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Missions/DJIMissionControl.html).

You wouldn't need to implement it either, you can access the singleton managed by the SDK through the [SDK Manager](http://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html#djisdkmanager_missioncontrol_inline):

```
DJISDKManager.missionControl
```

Comment: Thank you very much Arnaud !!